# Error 'LC_TYPE' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, setlocale

I'm writing program in c++ that is supposed to change letters in text to uppercase letters(Program works, but setlocale is not working). But it is giving me Error. [Error] 'LC_TYPE' was not declared in this scope. It "should" work because it is from my official faculty literature.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
cout << "Write something: " << endl;
string tekst; //tekst=text
getline(cin, tekst);

setlocale(LC_TYPE, "croatian"); // here is problem...

for (char znak : tekst){  //znak=char, symbol...
    char velikoSlovo = toupper(znak); // velikoSlovo=uppercaseLetter
    cout << velikoSlovo;
}
cout << endl;   
return 0;
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this??
I'm using Orwell Dev C++ 5.9.2. Language standard (-std) is ISO C++ 11.
[Here is picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXlkd.png)

Comment: `#include <clocale>`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Book says it is not necessary, but I will try this now.

Comment: #include <clocale> doesnt help, LC_CTYPE doesnt work.

Comment: Both comments are correct but you need to use them in combination.  If I do so, then your example compiles clean in C++11 on GCC even at highest warning levels.

Comment: @5gon12eder it compiles now but it is not working i.imgur.com/5MCMT1T.png č=Č š=Š

Comment: To define “not working”, we'd need to know what you expect from your program.

Comment: if i enter g it prints G, it transforms lowercase letter to uppercase.

Comment: @panda So you want a locale-sensitive way to convert a string to upper case?  If there is a standard C++ way to do this then I don't know it.  Surely, there are third-party libraries out there but it is interesting to note that `boost::to_upper` behaves the same.  Note that in general, this cannot work on a `char`-by`char` basis as multi-byte encodings are involved.  Matters get worse if you have uppercase forms that take more than a single character…

Comment: @5gon12eder it is working great without šđčćž, those letters are problem and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Probably because – unlike the other letters you have tried – those letters don't have a single-byte uppercase form in your locale's encoding.  See, you are dealing with `char`s and assuming it has 8 bits, a single `char` can only represent at most 256 distinct characters.

Comment: @5gon12eder could be, what to use then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to include `#include <clocale>` as it is said [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/)

Edit:
Actually `#include <locale.h>` should be preferred to `<clocale>` to reduce portability issues. Thanks to @Cheers for mentioning it in the comments.

Comment: @panda That's because you're using `LC_TYPE` instead of `LC_CTYPE`.

Comment: @Wintermute HolyBlackCat, it compiles now but it is not working http://i.imgur.com/5MCMT1T.png č=Č š=Š

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `<clocale>`, since that can more easily lead to portability problems, and has no advantages. Use `<locale.h>` for less problems. Don't know why the OP selected this as a solution, but as currently written it's a **bad** solution.

Comment: @Cheers the OP agree with you and will edit his answer right now. `<clocale>` is a bad habit that I should change. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, you should use `LC_CTYPE`:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/

Also you need to provide valid locale code, [as described here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Names.html#Locale-Names)

So for chroatian, your line should look like:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'hr_HR.UTF-8'); // or just "hr_HR"
```

or you can just use:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "")
```

which should set the localization to default locale used by your computer.

And as suggested before, you may also need to add `#include <clocale>`

Comment: it does not make them uppercase http://i.imgur.com/gvyrP9c.png :/ but prints them now, only it doesnt transform them

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it? it could be that

Comment: replace `"hr-HR"` with `'hr-HR.UTF-8'`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IMTtV5b.png , doesnt change anything :/, could it be compiler/software bug/error?

Comment: or try also `'hr_HR'`.

Comment: try `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` - it should set the localization to default locale used by your computer

Comment: Also there might be some windows-related problem, so you could try `'Croatian_Croatia.1250'` instead of `'hr_HR'`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#include <locale.h>
```

to get a declaration of `setlocale` and its associated constants.

In general just read the [relevant **documentation**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) of whatever function or associated things the compiler doesn't seem to recognize.

---

In general the chosen approach may work with single-byte oriented encodings, but not with multibyte encodings such as UTF-8. Single-byte encodings are commonly used in Windows. In Unix-land it's UTF-8 that rules.

And for Windows, you generally want the system's default locale, so instead of

```
setlocale(LC_TYPE, "croatian");
```

you may (but is not necessarily, but may with a good chance) be better served by

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

where the empty string selects the system locale rather than the default pure ASCII "C" locale.

---

Also, note that `toupper` from the C library requires a non-negative argument, or else the special value `EOF`. You can just cast the argument to `unsigned char`, when you know that it's not `EOF`.

Comment: @panda: Since your comment is not relevant to this answer, you shouldn't place it here. It looks as if your code now compiles, but you have run into a problem with *how it works*. You can post a new question about that. ;-)

Comment: and hth. -Afi , I apologise. setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); , doesnt work, but may be because my system is on english.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to check the return value of `std::setlocale` to see if it returned a `nullptr` indicating failure.